# how to build an string array from a string and integers in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have to put in a string array some values resulting from several parsed html pages. So the first value it's a name and all the others are numbers. After I must return the array to main to print. Obviously I make something wrong .

this is part of my newbie code...

```
String[] ret = null;
int y = 0;

for (Element h1 : h1s) {
    // Using Jsoup to scrape the html file and find H1 text
    h1_id = h1.className();
    // I put here the text of H1
    h1_text = h1.text();

    if (h1_id.equals("ezomat-logo-text ezCSS")) {
        // jump to the next h1
    } else {
        // I want to put the txt as the first array place
        ret[y] = "'" + h1_text + "'";
    }

    i = 0;
    // found the number values single integers with comma
    for (Element image : images) {
        Imm[i] = "," + imageName;
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    y = 1;

    // y = 1 because I want to start from the second position.
    for (Element image : images) {
        ret[y] = Imm[i];
        i++;
        y++;
    }

}
return ret;
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the Array after you return it?

Comment: Also, please format your source code - it's *really* hard to read at the moment. Also note that you're never initializing `ret` to any value other than `null`... perhaps you should use a `List<String>` instead so you can just add to it?

Comment: **Your question is very unclear**, What exactly do you wish to achieve?

Comment: @bali182 Thank you for the formatting. Next time I will be more carefully.

Comment: @Jon Skeet True! I'm sorry next time I will be more carefull. bye

Comment: @Vanitas ok, "I need to build a string array with the values extrapolated from a parsed html page". I've already find the answer... and was the same you gave me(I notice just now). thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first line of your code you attempt to define an array without a size, but **you don't actually define it**, you just assign `null`.
Also, it's impossible to dynamically add elements to such array.

For these scenarios we have `List`.
To define a `List` that stores Strings use the following code:

```
List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String> ();
```

And then proceed to add elements to this array like so:

```
ret.add ("," + imageName);
```

To retrieve a value from an index in the list do the following:

```
ret.get(index);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't dynamicly resize an array, you have to initialize it with a fixed size.

- So, you have to initialize it with

  ```
  String[] ret = new String[size];
  ```

where `size` have to be the number of elements you are going to put into your array.

- Or the better approach: Use `ArrayList<String>`instead. Initialize it with

  ```
  ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
  ```

and add your Items with `ret.add("whatever");`.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not allow arrays with variable length. I think that this is your main problem.
There are two choiches:

- Obtain the array length first and instantiate the array accordingly

  ```
  String[] ret = new String[100];
  ```
- Use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

  ```
  ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
  ```

You can add elements to the `ArrayList` like this: `ret.add(value);`

[The Java Tutorial: Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
[java.util.ArrayList reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)